# Parse data doesn't show up on table view

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to query an existing data from parse to iOS table view using swift, every time i run the app it doesn't show anything on the table view controller

here's the code

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class UserTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var users = [""]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        println(PFUser.currentUser())

        var query = PFUser.query()

        query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            for object in objects! {
                var user: PFUser = object as! PFUser
                self.users.append(user.username!)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = users[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }


}
```

I don't get any error in this code, its just the data didn't get to append to the users array. I'm pretty sure that is the cause of the problem, but I just couldn't figure it out.

edited keep getting this breakpoint after running the app

[image]

Comment: Do you get any results from your query?

Comment: Hello Christian, thank you for the reply. How do i check it? is it using println() ?

Comment: Yes. I would just print out the object in your for-loop where you append the  username to your array. You should also check if there is an error. So print out the error too. println(error)

Comment: If the query is returning results, you might also need to execute the reloadData on the UI thread. You can use parse executors for this.

Comment: @Christian take a look at my edited question, i keep getting this breakpoint after running the app

Comment: You maybe have set a breakpoint. Check if there is a blue arrow on the left side of your line where you get a breakpoint and delete it.

Comment: wow christian, thank you so much can you please put this as an answer so i can accept . Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe have set a breakpoint. Check if there is a blue arrow on the left side of your line where you get a breakpoint and delete it,